# Error:(36, 33) Dimension types not allowed (at 'backgroundTint' with value '22dp')

Tags: android

i have this problem when i trin to run the app on the phone

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.itayb.wob.LoginActivity2">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="E-mil"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:backgroundTint="22dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Password"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Connect"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginLeft="294dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="294dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" />
```

and i have one more problem

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\ItayB\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line `android:backgroundTint="22dp"` must be a color.

Something line `android:backgroundTint="#FF0000"` or `android:backgroundTint="@color/red"`

Comment: i have problem Error:(24, 6) error: reached end of file while parsing

Answer (score 0):

Your `TextView` with id textView2 has a `backgroundTint` of 22dp it should be a reference or a color value